# Podcast aggregation - please recommend for Windows 7

Tags: podcasts, aggregation

I need a good podcast aggregator. I was using Juice 2.2, but that will not work on my new PC which is running Windows 7 64-bit. Could anyone recommend one?

I need the following functionality:

1. Subscribes to podcasts (MP3s from radio shows) using RSS
2. Has OPML support so I can load up my old subscriptions easily
3. Runs quietly in the backgrond and looks after itself
4. Deletes old episodes automatically after a set time
5. Isn't just designed for an iPod (I use a simple generic MP3 player to listen).

Any ideas?

Comment: I have run Juice fine on my 64bit machine. Have you tried to set it to emulate XP SP2 or SP3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try running Juice in Windows 7's [Windows XP Mode](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/default.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Mike. This does indeed work...  Note for others: XP Mode is available only on Windows 7 Professional or Enterprise versions.

Comment: You can run Juice without using Windows XP Mode. Set Juice.exe in compatibility mode for Windows XP (this can be done via the file's properties).

Answer (score 0):

Some options are:

- [WinPodder](http://winpodder.com/) was developed to be simple to use.
- [ZiePod](http://www.ziepod.com/) (don't know much about this one)
- [Podcast Ready](http://www.podcastready.com/) syncs with their website and can run on a USB key.

Some referenced via [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_podcatchers)